# How to put UIActivityIndicator left in navigation controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I have ViewController in which is WebView (loading web site inside) and I want on start loading to show UIActivityIndicator left in navigation controller and when loading is done remove it.

I have ViewController with embed navigation controller and I've tryed to put over IB UIIndicator but with no success, it's put in content part so pls tell me how programmatically put indicator in navigation bar left side.

Thank's for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to put an activity indicator in the nav bar using only storyboards, unfortunately.

Create an instance variable for the activity indicator:

```
@implementation
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}
...
```

In your `viewDidLoad` method, instantiate it and add it to the navigation bar:

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
```

The property `hidesWhenStopped` is `YES` by default, so it will hide when it's not animating automatically. All you have to do is call `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` when you want it to be visible or hidden, respectively.

Comment: I've created SingleViewController, add for ViewController "Emded in Navigation" and put your code + startAnimating in viewDidLoad but it is not showing up.

Comment: Yup, sorry, my fault. There was a small problem with the code. I've editing it and tested it in a fresh project and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```